# unable to download elementary OS

Tags: download

when I try to click Purchase elementary OS nothing happens. I tried in different computers, incognito mode, deactivating adblock and extensions and nothing.

Comment: I had to try a few times when I just tested. It appears that the Stripe bits are slowing it down. I refreshed each time, putting 0.00 in the price section, and then clicking on the purchase button. It took a few tries but it eventually went through.

Comment: even when i put 0 in the price section nothing happens D:

Comment: You may want to try '0.00'.

Comment: nothing, it is still showing Purchase (even when i put 0.00 lol) i downloaded elementary OS before and i had no problems. i guess i gotta keep trying

Comment: How weird. I can confirm the site works with Chromium - though it took a few tries. It seemed to get hung up on the Stripe bit. If I were you, my next step would be to go bug them by chat [in their Slack channel](https://community-slack.elementary.io/). Let them know their site is messing up. It may well be a fluke that I got through after the 3rd attempt. Either way, it shouldn't take 3 attempts.

Comment: [Here is a direct link for you](https://nyc3.dl.elementary.io/download/MTYxNTMxNTg4OQ==/elementaryos-5.1-stable.20200814.iso).

Comment: thank you! i swear i still cannot download the iso :(