# Purchase elementary OS button unresponsive

Tags: download

The "Purchase elementary OS" button in elementary.io page doesn't work. I tried with safari, brave and Firefox on multiple Mac's. It doesn't matter whether I select a preset amount or enter a custom amount, the button never changed to "Download ...".

Is there a workaround you could suggest?

Thanks,
David

Comment: It took a few tries. Do you have 3rd party stuff like scripts and cookies disabled? If so, that would probably do it. Anyhow, for a short (maybe 24 hours but I'm guessing) while, [this link](https://nyc3.dl.elementary.io/download/MTYxNTc4MDcxNA==/elementaryos-5.1-stable.20200814.iso) should do the trick for you. That should download it directly.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/26642/unable-to-download-elementary-os.