# Purchase button won't work on https://elementary.io/ website

Tags: download

Using Brave, Firefox and Safari on macOS 11.2, clicking the "Purchase" button does nothing.
Is there an alternate way to get eOS?

Comment: I am not sure how long this will be valid. Click [here](https://nyc3.dl.elementary.io/download/MTYxNjExMjE4MA==/elementaryos-5.1-stable.20200814.iso). I had to try Chrome and Opera and it triggered on the second try with Opera. I just entered "0.00" in the custom section.

Comment: This one is also a duplicate of https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/26642/unable-to-download-elementary-os